# Terraform apply with -target no work, but with double dash work well --target

Tags: terraform

I want launch individual modules with -target option but I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\alexm\Desktop\projects\terraform\tf-ia> terraform apply -target=module.ec2_test 
╷
│ Error: Invalid target "module"
│
│ Prefix "module." must be followed by a module name.
```

But if I use double dash,work fine:

```
PS C:\Users\alexm\Desktop\projects\terraform\tf-ia> terraform apply --target=module.ec2_test

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.ec2_test.aws_instance.app_server will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-830c94e3"
      + arn                                  = (known after apply)...........................
....................................................
```

I launch this from root folder proyect
[image folders proyect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZqWu.png)

Why is this?
I am doing it right?

Comment: What is your directory tree?

Comment: I sent photo and run in root folder